how to handle audio-messages in python-telegram-bot
I want bot to check if user answer have audio and then decide what to do but bot only handle text message and just ignores audio.
I have this handler
async def self_problem(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    conn = sqlite3.connect(database='db.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()

Then here new should be check if message have text ot not(because audio should do not have text i believe), but bit just ignores if I send audio-message and will only reply after text message
    if update.message.text:
        query = f"update users set problem = '{update.message.text}' where id = {context.user_data['user_id']}"
    else:
        audio_file = update.message.audio
        new_file = await context.bot.get_file(audio_file.file_id)
        audio_path = f'audio/{audio_file.file_unique_id}.ogg'
        await new_file.download(audio_path)

        query = f"insert into audio ('id', 'audio_name') values ({context.user_data['user_id']}, '{audio_path}')"
        cur.execute(query)
        conn.commit()

        query = f"update users set problem = 'в аудио-сообщении' where id = {context.user_data['user_id']}"

    cur.execute(query)
    conn.commit()
    print(query, 'executed', sep='\n')
    conn.close()

    await context.bot.send_video(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, video=video_for_11)
    await context.bot.send_video(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, video=video_end)
    return await before_reg_or_num(update, context)


And this in ConversationHandler
SELF_PROBLEM:        [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT | filters.AUDIO, self_problem)],

I didnt found any handler to handle audio thus I just did filters.AUDIO
